# Highchart yAxis plotLines label position

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am having an issue of relocate yAxis.plotLines.label position.
[image]

I want to move label from original position to under the plotLine.
Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/a3pwnwqj/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: 100,
            label: {
                text: 'Plot line',
                align: 'right'
            }
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to say plot line at 90 ?

Comment: eww, actually, I want to move label text to under plotLine not at the top of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check [xAxis.plotLines.label.y](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.label.y) to adjust the label positin

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32cLh3co/) demo

```
 yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        value: 100,
        label: {
            text: 'Plot line',
            align: 'right',
            y: 20, /*moves label down*/
        }
    }]
},
```

Comment: But its not responsive, label is coming inside the chart
https://jsfiddle.net/1er0aw93/
I want to keep it outside the chart no matter what is the label size